# Is this a possible sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

- This game is tired me.

What I want to say is that I am tired of the game.

I thought this sentence would be correct because 'I am finished reading' is used.

I want to learn about 'be + past participle' constructions when they don't mean passive.

Comment: I have on idea why you think "I am finished reading" and "This game is tired me" are similar... they are completely unrelated and have no similarities in structure or word order! I suppose people make mistakes to learn though, haha. If you want to say you are tired of this game, you can say "I am fed up with this game" or "I'm tired of this game".

Comment: @AricFowler haha. It is just why I made mistakes that I am so curious a man interested in English. Anyway, May you tell me about 'be + past participle' constructions when they do not mean passive, but like 'I am finished reading'? If you can, I will more thank for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "*be* + past participle construction that isn't passive" in Modern English.

In *I am finished*, *finished* is an adjective, not a verb.

Answer (score 1):

"I am finished reading" is a chimaera, a mixture of two valid constructions that results in a sentence that is grammatically odd (and perhaps invalid)

"I am finished" is valid. It is formed with an adjective as the complement of "I am".

And as a verb, "to finish reading" is correct, so "I have finished reading" is a valid sentence.  But "I am finished reading" mixes these two structures. It is clearly understandable, and perhaps it is a special case, or "reading" can be understood as some kind of participle modifier of the adjective.

The structure "I am finished" is not a passive construction.  Given "I finish reading", a passive voice sentence would be "Reading is finished by me" (but this is very non-idiomatic.

"I am tired of the game" is also an active construction with an adjective "tired" and a prepositional phrase modifying tired "of the game". Since the verb here is not a transitive verb, there is no passive form. In particular "the game is tired me" is ungrammatical English.

In general, you can't make passive voice sentences with "be"-verbs. "It is an apple" (okay) but "An apple is been by it" (incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds terribly wrong.
The closest correct version is

> This game has tired me

but even if it is correct it sounds a bit boring.

I would say something like

> I'm tired of this game

or more informally

> I'm done with this game

Comment: "I am known how to resolve this problem." Is it terribly wrong  as well?

Comment: That would be "I know how to resolve this problem"

Comment: "I am known" is the same as "People know me" and still the syntax is wrong. RickL got it right

Comment: Why is it wrong? I want to know the reason.

Comment: Beacause even if you use "I am know", which again changes completely the meaning of the phrase, you still need to connect somehow to the rest of the phrase "how to resolve this problem". It could be someting like "I am known as somebody who can solve this problem". Still, the meaning of the entire phrase is not like the original one. It sounds unnecessarly pompous and artificial.

Comment: @Coreplo: I would just point out that the (as you imply, relatively unusual) utterance *This game has tired me* would normally be understood to mean *[playing] this game has **exhausted** me,* (not *I have become **bored with** this game*).

Comment: You're right, my answer wasn't that precise. Thanks for pointing it out.